# Populate view with data from web-service/API

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use data for an API in React Native to create multiple views.

I have used the code below but the page renders before the web service response so i keep this error:

Unhandled JS Exception: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.user.map')

```
export default class Component6 extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        user: null
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUsers();
}

fetchUsers() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {

            this.setState({

            });
        });
}



render() {
    contents = this.state.user.map(function (item) {
        return (
            <View key={item.id} style={styles.content}>
                <Text>{item.email}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    });
    return (
          {contents}
    );
}
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Component6', () => Component6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an 'if' statement, and also its better to move your contents outside of render so it's not redefining it on every render:

```
export default class Component6 extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        user: null
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUsers();
}

fetchUsers() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
            item = this.viewconstur(response),

            this.setState({
              user: item
            });
        });
}

  renderContents = () => {
    if (this.state.user) {
      this.state.user.map((item) => (
        <View key={item.id} style={styles.content}>
          <Text>{item.email}</Text>
        </View>
      ));
    }
  }

render() {
    return (
          <View>
            {this.renderContents()}
          </View>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: thanks, i no longer get the error above but the view is blank

Comment: The view is only going to show if your fetch was successful, also you need to edit your fetchUsers to provide the correct information to this.setState...